# Ejecutar .py desde USB

Tags: python, usb

La cuestión es la siguiente, tengo 1 archivo .py y un txt. (en el cual escribe unos resultados python). Necesito poder ejecutarlos en otro pc, sin la necesidad de tene intérprete o compilador.

He probado a convertirlo en exe. con Pyinstaller pero se distorsiona algunas características (ej. formato del texto, color...). Entonces decidí usar WinPhyton, teniéndo las aplicaciones portables y funciona a la perfección en el USB.

El problema es que, al cambiar el usb de terminal, la letra del USB se modifica, modificandose asi las rutas y dando error al ejecutar programas. No sé de que manera puedo hacer para mantener la letra fija en TODOS los terminales, ya que en uno sí se, pero no me es de utilidad. He leido acerca de archivos Bath, de crear un entorno en el usb, o usar % ~ d0, pero no consigo comprenderlo. Mil gracias.

Comment: Deberías tratar de trabajar con rutas relativas, de ese modo la unidad o incluso el directorio dará igual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo ocupas acceder al .txt que habita en la misma carpeta que la aplicación podrías utilizar rutas relativas. Algo similar a esto:

```
import os 
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
filename = os.path.join(dir, '/archivo.txt')
```

En donde:

```
import os
```

Es el modulo para manejar los directorios.

```
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Obtiene el directorio en donde habita tu programa (unidad de USB), por ejemplo E:/

```
filename = os.path.join(dir, '/archivo.txt')
```

Crea la ruta de acceso para el archivo txt.

Espero que sea de ayuda, desconozco la compatibilidad del método con WinPython.